# I am getting this error in command prompt 'spark-shell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, java-8, installation

[image]I have installed Java8, Spark 2.4.4 inside C:\ drive in my windows (64 bit system). All the installation I have done as per the document I received for the installation. However when I am running spark-shell command in cmd its giving below error, All the environment variables are set.

[image: Error in cmd while running spark-shell command[![enter image description here][image: ][1]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwMK5.png)

Comment: "You have add the bin path of Spark" in path environment variable variable.Like mine is C:\BigDataTools\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can add, SPARK_HOME/bin to the PATH at command line as well.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%SPARK_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: Glad to see, if this has solved your problem. Then you can accept this answer, tnx

Answer (score 0):

**"You have add the bin path of Spark"** in path environment variable variable.Like mine is C:\BigDataTools\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\bin

Answer (score 0):

Try adding hadoop into path:

```
%HADOOP_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
 Try to provide answers not as questions.